# "На службе великой страны"

Tags: стилистика

Верно ли выражение "На службе великой страны"?

Answer (score 2):

Слова "На службе великой страны" есть в песне про десантников (http://luk-media.ru/vdv_4.php) и в списке креативный рекламных лозунгов (http://reklamasmex.blogspot.co.il/p/blog-page_09.html)

Подобные сочетания слов (на службе чего-либо) можно найти в Нацкорпусе:

> Стать беззаветным героем на службе человечества, к которому будут приходить в минуту сомнений и духовного упадка… [Виктор Пелевин. Любовь к трем цукербринам (2014)]
>
> Рождество на службе эксплуататоров. Чему учит сказание о Рождестве. [Елена Душечкина. Дед Мороз и Снегурочка // «Отечественные записки», 2003]
>
> Мафия на службе народа Европейским беднякам будут помогать из средств, конфискованных у бандитов [Николай Анищенко. Мафия на службе народа // «Русский репортер», 2014]

Comment: Служба человечества - это правильно? Какое значение у этого выражения?

Comment: @Jasmin    Я тоже не знаю, как это объяснить, но что делать с примерами из Нацкорпуса? Там ведь не только Пелевин. Всех объявить еретиками?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется правильным выражение **"на службе у великой страны"**.

Непонятно, откуда взялся родительный беспредложный падеж.

Служба ― это конкретная  организация, есть, например, различные службы города (городские службы).

**СЛУЖБА** 5. чего или какая. Отрасль производства или учреждение, организация, ведающие какой-л. специальной областью работы. Медицинская с. Метеорологическая с. **СЛУЖИТЬ** 5. кому-чему. Работать, трудиться во имя чего-л., на благо кого-, чего-л. С. народу.

**Но что такое служба страны?** Если это служение, то правильно говорить "служба/служение стране".

Примеры

В антирождественской кампании приняли участие поэты, состоявшие **на службе у советской власти,** как, например, Демьян Бедный.

Тут же вызвали к начальству и объяснили, причём… э-э… в категорической форме, что я не имею права заниматься самодеятельностью, что я не волк-одиночка, а офицер милиции, **на службе у государства…**

**Но у Пелевина:** Стать беззаветным героем **на службе человечества**, к которому будут приходить в минуту сомнений и духовного упадка… [Виктор Пелевин. Любовь к трем цукербринам (2014)]

**И что такое служба человечества?**

Answer (score 1):

**Верно ли выражение "На службе великой страны"?**

Да, верно. Подобное употребление не просто часто встречается — оно встречается в энциклопедиях (в хороших изданиях), в официальных документах, даже в названиях наград.

Посмотрите для примера [этот ответ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=290386) справочной службы Грамота.ру.

К сожалению, я не нашёл объяснения такому употреблению — это было бы действительно интересно понять.

Upd.1. Плохо дело: на Грамоте.ру нашёлся точно [такой же вопрос](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=225858) с противоположным ответом. Но это не отменяет других многочисленных авторитетных примеров.

Upd.2. Дополню ответ авторитетными источниками.

- "Фонология **на службе обучения** произношению неродного
  языка", лингвист, доктора филологических наук А.А. Реформатский.
- Вестник Московского университета. Сер.9, Филология: Инструкции к медикаментам: Лингвистика **на службе практики**.
- "Лингвистика **на службе методики**", Е.А. Буданова, кандидат пед. наук, доцент.
- "Парадигма для определения латерализации языка в мозге: естественнонаучный метод **на службе лингвистики**", Вестник Российского Фонда Фундаментальной Науки.
- Числа **на службе лингвистики** // Кондратов А. Звуки и знаки. — М.: Знание, 1966.
- и пр.

Comment: Тогда должно существовать сочетание "служба человечества". Может быть, есть такая, вот о чем надо у Грамоты спрашивать.  Мне кажется, что у людей испортился слух, они перестали обращать внимание на явно ошибочную речь. И тогда вот такие "службы" пробираются в язык и закрепляются там. И здесь (в ломке грамматики) действительно таится опасность для развития русского языка, а вовсе не в большом количестве заимствованных слов.

Comment: @Jasmin В этом случае у меня нет объяснения. Но если в данном конкретном случае моё "чувство языка" было испорчено, то это произошло ещё в советские времена. Выражение "на службе Родины" встречаются ещё с [середины прошлого века](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=wPkZAAAAYAAJ&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B5+%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%22&dq=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B5+%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicpuT1-qDZAhVHr6QKHV-JByA4FBDoAQgpMAE).

Comment: Ну ладно, пусть это будет такая ЕДИНАЯ ВИРТУАЛЬНАЯ СЛУЖБА, в штате которой мы все числимся и работаем,  - служба страны. Надо только хорошо представить себе этот образ и привыкнуть к нему.

Comment: Специальные службы есть в словаре: 5. Отрасль производства или учреждение, организация, ведающие какой-л. специальной областью работы.  С. быта. С. связи. С. мер и весов. Нет только службы великой страны и службы человечества

Comment: @Jasmin Да, я сразу обратил на это внимание. Но я постарался выбрать цитаты (я добавил их в ответ) профессиональных лингвистов или филологов, в которых или лингвистика служит кому-то или кто-то находится на службе лингвистики. Таких цитат встречается намного больше — их море, так что мне трудно представить, что можно против этого возразить.

Comment: "На службе практики, методики, лингвистики"  можно заменить "на практической, методической, лингвистической службе" . Здесь определительное значение Р.п. А для сочетания  "на службе страны"  такой замены не сделаешь,  вот оно и раздражает слух.